# Is "probability of probability" precise language?

Tags: probability

I was reading [this Wikipedia artice on solar flares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare) and came across the following wording:

> According to NASA, there may be as much as a 12% chance of a similar
>   event occurring between 2012 and 2022

Is this mathematically precise language? Does it make sense to say that there is a probability of the probability being 0.12? Even if it is precise, it seems pretty vacuous to me, given that this probability of probability may be anything $\geq 0$.

Comment: How is this different from saying that "there is a $12\%$ chance of rain tomorrow"?  It is true, of course, that there's no very good way of testing a one-off statement like this.  If the event happens...is that evidence against the prediction?   Iterated predictions (like weather reports) can be tested over time.  My guess, for your NASA thing, is that this is an actuarial type prediction...no?  A recurring astronomical event, or something, and we have historical data to work from.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: I see nothing like "probability of the probability" here. Can you explain ?

Comment: @lulu I somewhat agree but assuming there's some true value of the probability around $0.12$ it might have some error associated. In any case, "probability of probability" is ghastly and they could report it as "probability is approximately", which they've essentially done.

Comment: @Jam  But I don't see that phrase anywhere, except in the OP's own title.

Comment: @Jam  The actual language from the article is :"According to NASA, there may be as much as a 12% chance of a similar event occurring between 2012 and 2022,[5] although because this particular figure was based on an extreme extrapolation of the calculated frequency of future storms, the actual probability of this is almost certainly rather lower than 12 percent." This seems entirely sensible, no?

Comment: @lulu Yeah I agree it's fine. I was trying to say that OP's suggestion was a bit hard to read. Since they've said "as much as", they're correct if the true probability is anywhere from $0$ to $12\%$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, the statement says "there *may* be as much as a 12% chance" -- it says that the probability of the statement "There is a 12% chance of some event occurring" being true is some definable $p$.

Comment: @horse: I understand this as saying that the probability can be $12\%$, but not necessarily (depending on some circumstance). It's an upper bound. By the way, if you talk about an estimator of a probability (say of a Bernouilli scheme), the estimator indeed has a distribution, so that the probability has a probability.

Comment: @horse  But what's wrong with that?  Let's say i want to estimate the probability that the river near me will flood in the next five years.  Straight actuarial evidence yields $1\%$.  However, I fear that global warming has increased the chance, so I run the most  extreme, pessimistic model of climate change I can find and now I get $5\%$. I think it would then be reasonable to say "the probability is less than $5\%$".

Comment: Mathematically is correct. From a formal point of view we dont care about the composition of $\Omega$ if it measurable. Observe that the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) is used to model "probabilities of probabilities" in many cases.